# opencv: video stabilization module sample failing for any video with different errors

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

running the video stabilization module sample with any video, fails with different errors tried it with different files and it is always failing:

```
[theATeamMBP:ghooo]~/Projects/opencv/samples/cpp$ ./cpp-example-videostab ~/Documents/My\ Movie.mp4 -q
frame count (rough): 5
first pass: estimating motions.x..
motion estimation time: 0.539 sec
motion stabilization time: 0.000 sec
estimated trim ratio: 0.001953
processing frames.......................Segmentation fault: 11
[theATeamMBP:ghooo]~/Projects/opencv/samples/cpp$ ./cpp-example-videostab ~/Documents/My\ Movie.mp4 -q
frame count (rough): 5
first pass: estimating motions.x..
motion estimation time: 0.544 sec
motion stabilization time: 0.000 sec
estimated trim ratio: 0.001953
processing frames.......................OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows) in Mat, file /Users/ghooo/Projects/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 494
error: /Users/ghooo/Projects/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:494: error: (-215) 0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows in function Mat

[theATeamMBP:ghooo]~/Projects/opencv/samples/cpp$ ./cpp-example-videostab ~/Documents/My\ Movie.mp4 -q
frame count (rough): 5
first pass: estimating motions.x..
motion estimation time: 0.534 sec
motion stabilization time: 0.000 sec
estimated trim ratio: 0.001953
processing frames.......................cpp-example-videostab(5838,0x7fff726a3300) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=4464468642439168) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
OpenCV Error: Insufficient memory (Failed to allocate 4464468642436064 bytes) in OutOfMemoryError, file /Users/ghooo/Projects/opencv/modules/core/src/alloc.cpp, line 52
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (u != 0) in create, file /Users/ghooo/Projects/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 410
error: /Users/ghooo/Projects/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:410: error: (-215) u != 0 in function create
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [opencv installation guide](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html) I have had to install the required package ffmpeg. I already did that, but what was not written is I have to cmake opencv with use_ffmpeg flag set to yes like this 
`cmake -D USE_FFMPEG=YES .`

now everything works just fine, except for the sound in the resulting video is not working still figuring it out.